# Why is my C++ exception not being caught?

Tags: c++, exception

My code throws `std::runtime_error`, but doesn't catch it in the `catch` block. Instead it just calls `std::terminate` or, if I declared an exception-specifier on a function, calls `std::unexpected`.

The code simplifies down to:

```
void myfunc()
{
   throw new std::runtime_error("always throw");
}

int main()
{
    try {
        myfunc();
    } catch (std::runtime_error &err) {
        std::cerr << "intentionally ignored exception: " << err.what() << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }
    std::cerr << "unreachable?" << std::endl;
    return 1;
}
```

Similarly, if I add a `throw` specifier on my function, I crash out with `std::unknown`.

```
void myfunc() throw (std::runtime_error)
{
   throw new std::runtime_error("always throw");
}
```

Comment: Posted because I didn't find this info quickly and wanted to make it trivially discoverable. It's clearly been way too long since I wrote c++.

Comment: `throw (std::runtime_error)`  is generally considered a waste of time in C++.  Only declaring nothrow is considered useful.

Comment: `throw (std::runtime_error)`is depricated since C++11 and removed in C++17.

Answer (score 10):

You slipped in a Java-ism:

```
throw new std::runtime_error("always throw")
      ^^^
```

This causes the `catch` clause not to match, because it matches by type and you throw `std::runtime_error*`, i.e. a *pointer to* a `std::runtime_error`. It's expecting a plain `std::runtime_error` *by-reference*.

You could (untested) catch your original exception with

```
catch (std::runtime_error * exc) /* don't do this */
```

but you shouldn't do that.

Instead skip the `new`; throw your exception directly and write:

```
void myfunc()
{
   throw std::runtime_error("always throw");
}
```

C++ is smart enough that if you catch the exception by-reference it won't get copied around.

Also, as @KonradRudolph points out in the comments, you should catch by const-reference:

```
catch (const std::runtime_error &err)
```

Comment: Small improvement: you should almost(?) always catch by `const` ref.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Catching by const reference doesn't matter - the exception provided is a copy already and the const is superfluous. All it does is highlight your intention to not change the exception.  (If you planned to change it; catching it by reference is perfectly reasonable)

Comment: @UKMonkey It’s hardly superfluous. Signalling intent is exactly why it should be used here — and also elsewhere: make *everything* `const` that isn’t supposed to be mutated. There’s a large consensus that this is a good thing™.

Comment: @KonradRudolph sure; but if you "Almost(?) always" modify the exception in the catch, then you should "Almost always" not include const.  The point is that the exception is modifiable should you want it to be;  and the language will not force you to catch a const object ever.